# In the Instagram API how to access basic user information for 'Private Users'?

Tags: instagram, http-status-code-400, instagram-api

I don't really understand why instagram api prohibits access to information public in 'private users' (#counts, #username,#profile picture)

This works well for public users but for private users returns:

> {   "meta":   {
>         "code":400,
>         "error_message":"you cannot view this resource",
>         "error_type":"APINotAllowedError"   }
>   }

help!
thanks

Comment: unless you are friends with that user (and authenticated as yourself), you cannot access that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called Private users as their information cannot be accessed, there is no way using the API you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can only see them by searching by the username, and have the chance that it returns the user you are searching for.